# Binding Run object in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, embedded, silverlight-3.0

I have 2 questions.

1st.
I am using Silverlight for windows embedded compact 7 and i have some problems with bindings.

i have template like this

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="VoltageTab">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="95"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="61"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="193,0,192,3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="#00000000">
                            <Image x:Name="UnCheckedimg" Source="12.png"/>
                            <Image x:Name="Checkedimg" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="11.png"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ModeName" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Alternate_Gothic_No.ttf#Alternate-Gothic-No3" Text="VOLTAGE" Foreground="#D25A32" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock  x:Name="ModeValue" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Alternate_Gothic_No.ttf#Alternate-Gothic-No3" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ModeNameChecked" Visibility="Collapsed" FontSize="34" FontFamily="Alternate_Gothic_No.ttf#Alternate-Gothic-No3" Text="VOLTAGE" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I use TemplateBinding to bind ModeValue textblock, but i need another binding to bind ModeName. Can somone point me how to do this?

2. I have another style

EDIT: 2nd style is posted below because editor didnt alowe me to post it here

It works ok if i only put text into content, but i want to you Run objects so i can format text inside buttons.

Is this possible and if not is there some other way to achive this?

Please keep in mind that i use Silverlight For Windows embedded.

Best regards,
Luka

---

```
 <Style x:Key="FunctionSelectButton" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="154"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="61"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="#00000000">
                        <Image x:Name="NormalImg" Source="mode_unpressed.png" Stretch="None"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalText" Foreground="#D25A32" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Alternate_Gothic_No.ttf#Alternate-Gothic-No3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Image for easyer representation -> [image]

Comment: Hey Luka, I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking but if maybe you can make a quick a picture of what you want it might help describe it better?

Comment: I did a picture, i hope its more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, [look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177974/How-to-implement-Template-Binding-in-Silverlight-C).

Your 2nd question though, I'm not sure I understand entirely what the question is, but what I think you're looking for would be setting it as a ContentPresenter with contenttemplate instead like;

```
<Style x:Key="FunctionSelectButton" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="154"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="61"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="NormalImg" Source="mode_unpressed.png" Stretch="None"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />

<!--
<TextBlock x:Name="NormalText" Foreground="#D25A32" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Alternate_Gothic_No.ttf#Alternate-Gothic-No3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
-->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

---

```
<Button Content="{Binding RPE-2WIRE}" Style="{StaticResource FunctionSelectButton}" FontFamily="Alternate_Gothic_No.ttf#Alternate-Gothic-No3" Foreground="#D25A32" FontSize="26" />
```

At least that's what I think you're saying :)

Comment: Hi, i just spent 8 hours trying to figure out how to get Dependency Propertys working with no success :(, Chris is there any way to contact you? My email is: luka.pivk[at]avspekter.si or skype: vevrcaa if you are willing to help me a bit. Best regards, Luka

Comment: As for the 2nd question, i solved it using your solution, TNX!